# Split images when creating custom dataset function

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision

I have 5000x5000X3 sized images, I want to split image into multiple smaller images. I have tried to create dataset with splitted images. But it occupies more space and is very tedious task to manage those images. Then I tried to create a pipeline where images are split while training. But confused with how to implement it as pytorch custom dataset class.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
from torchvision.io import read_image

class CustomImageDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, annotations_file, img_dir, transform=None, target_transform=None):
          self.img_labels = pd.read_csv(annotations_file)
          self.img_dir = img_dir
          self.transform = transform
          self.target_transform = target_transform

   def __len__(self):
         return len(self.img_labels)

  def __getitem__(self, idx):
        img_path = os.path.join(self.img_dir, self.img_labels.iloc[idx, 0])
        image = read_image(img_path)
        label = self.img_labels.iloc[idx, 1]
        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)
        if self.target_transform:
            label = self.target_transform(label)
        return image, label
```

Answer (score 0):

Please first look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72642001/9560771
and make sure if you like to use `online augmentations` and `offline augmentations`

If you like offline you must save the small images onto the disk.

Else, using online you can use `transforms.RandomResizedCrop(XX)` to randomly crop small images from the input image